# D3 Canvas globe with animated text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas

I am using `d3` V4 with geoOrthographic to spin a 3d globe on a canvas.

I have followed and stitched a few example from bl.ocks.org to achieved that. I am new to `d3`.
So far I have the globe spinning and dots at some city location that appears and disappears accordingly with the globe rotation.

I have also attached the city name to the corresponding dots but I cannot managed to synchronies them with the dots.
So my city name does not appears or disappears at the same time with the dots.

here is a Codepen of my Globe.
[Codepen Canvas Globe](https://codepen.io/tomsah/pen/LmdKgV?editors=0010)
I have made a Globe that works as I want to but in SVG
[Codepen SVG Globe](https://codepen.io/tomsah/pen/bMLVwv)
however SVG is not possible for me because it is slowing down too much the application once added to it. So I have to go with canvas for performances reason.

I have tired a few solution/ideas from other post on Stackoverflow but could  not make it work.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code from your second example a little more precisely into your first example and it works:

```
outerArray.forEach(function(d) {
  const coordinate = [d[0], d[1]];
  const center = [width / 2, height / 2];
  gdistance =d3.geoDistance(coordinate,projection.invert(center));

  if(gdistance < 1.57079632679490) {
    context.fillText( 
    d[2],
    projection(d)[0], 
    projection(d)[1] 
    );  
  }  
});
```

Updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKwjWb?editors=0010).

Comment: Amazing, Thank you so much for that @Mark, It just works as expected.